# Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined (chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome-extension, referenceerror

I have an unexpected fault in my code. The code is inside chrome extension made by my friend, but I'm rigt now unable to contact him.
Extension works fine until now, so I don't know what happens during last weeks (maybe some updates...)

Fault:
Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined

So, problem is in this part of my code in bookmarklet.js

```
oknoObsah=oknoObsah+"<td align='center'><img onclick=\"setTimeout(function(){myFunction('"+encodeURIComponent(images[i].src)+"');}, 3000);document.getElementById('"+i+"').style.border='3px solid red';oldVybrano=document.getElementById('vybrano').value; if(oldVybrano!='' && oldVybrano!="+i+")document.getElementById(oldVybrano).style.border='0px solid red';document.getElementById('vybrano').value="+i+";\" src='"+images[i].src+"' id='"+i+"'  style='max-height:75px; max-width:75px; border: 0px solid red;'></td>";
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Without seeing a demo that I can test myself it sounds like https://crbug.com/912069 which was broken in Chrome 71 and fixed in 72. Either use a newer Chrome like a separately installable Canary or rework your content script so that part runs inside a page-level script ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879)).

Comment: You can try the app --> https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/post-to-wikidiyorg/ofdiejblenchnmhokkkghfmpfglgjfhp

Comment: Problem is, that through this extension you can chose any image from previously visited page and this image will be sent to WikiDIY form...this function is not working now...

Comment: Yep, my guess was right. See the "more info" link I gave.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this link. But I'm not experienced coder :-/, any hint how to solve it in my case?

Comment: Try replacing okno.document.write(oknoObsah) with the following code (make sure to reload the extension in the browser): okno.document.write('<script>document.write("' + JSON.stringify(oknoObsah) + '")</script>')

Comment: Not working :-(

Comment: Remove both lines with document.open and document.write and put this: okno.document.documentElement.appendChild(okno.document.createElement('script')).text = 'document.write(' + JSON.stringify(oknoObsah) + ')'

Comment: YOU ARE THE BEST! Thank you